# Debug python terminated in eclipse ( pydev )

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

Today i installed eclipse and pydev to code python language. however when i debug python code in eclipse i get error

[image]

```
warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"/usr/bin/python" "/home/ctnguyenvn/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.18.0_155965261_linux_gtk_x86_64/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_8.3.0.202104101217/pysrc/setup_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build.
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 41547)
hi supperman
```

after i run:

```
ctnguyenvn[~]$ python /home/ctnguyenvn/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.18.0_155965261_linux_gtk_x86_64/plugins/org.python.pydev.core_8.3.0.202104101217/pysrc/setup_cython.py build_ext --inplace
```

and re-debug then i still get terminated program (output still run to end line).
[image]

My question:

**Why program debugger not stop at breakpoint (line 7)?**

**Why program still run to line 9 although debugging terminated (left window) ?**

More info:

```
os: archlinux x64
eclipse: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
pydev plugin: 8.3.0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why it didn't stop at your breakpoint...

To diagnose this, please set an environment variable:

`PYDEVD_DEBUG=1` (you can set it in the launch configuration or in the interpreter preferences).

and create a ticket in https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/issues with the contents shown in this case.